# Altera FPGA (?) Datasheet

Tags: fpga, integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet

I salved a lot of ICs but this one I couldn't find (and is maybe interesting enough to be play with it, since I never used an FPGA).

It's from a semiconductor chip production machine (high likely) and the PCB was marked 'Rejected' (but hope most ICs work) and was in the electronics garbage bin. So I don't know exactly for what device it was meant for.

It seems to be an Altera EPC3TC32, but where can I find the datasheet? Altera.com forwards to Intel and there I cannot find it.

The package is QFP32.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What board is that from? A sample soldering board?

Comment: That is a cyclone III (EPC = cyclone, 3 = III). Landing page at https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/programmable/fpga/cyclone-iii.html

Comment: @RonBeyer I put some more details in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `EPC` devices are usually configuration devices (flash memory) not FPGAs. The Cyclone III FPGA part numbers would instead begin with `EP3C` (Cyclone III), and not `EPC3`.

You are correct there doesn't seem to be a matching part number. However I believe you may have misread the `3`, and it is actually a `2`.

That gives `EPC2TC32`, which is indeed an, albeit obsolete, Altera [flash memory device](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/612/cfg_cf52004-1299428.pdf). This is a 1.6Mbit Configuration Flash memory in a TQFP-32 package.

Comment: Thank you very much ... not sure if it will be that useful to play around with (having no FPGA or knowledge about it. Although if it's not related to FPGA maybe I can use it for something else.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers they're designed to store the bitstreams that program certain serie of FPGA (e.g. Cyclone and Cyclone II devices). Although in practice they are just serial flash memories so you could probably use it for something else. But given its obsolescence, probably not much use.

Comment: Also it has quite a l ot of pins and SPI flash memory is probably easier (WinBond) ... anyway, nice to have, and I learnt something new today (again).

Comment: Definitely not 3, which has a straight "head" stroke as opposed to a rounded "head" of 2.